# jsp Group chat with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

hello every one  i am trying to develop a jsp group chat with ajax..
 here is my index page

```
function SChat() {

    var uname = form1.uname.value;
    var msg = form1.msg.value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 2000)
         {
                document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

         }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.jsp?uname=" + uname + "&msg=" + msg",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Html :

```
<form name="form1" >
        Enter Your Chat name <input type="text" name="uname"> </br>
        Message <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
        </br>
        <a href ="#" onclick="SChat()">send</a>
        </br>
        <div id="chatlogs">
            llllllll
        </div>
</form>
```

and here is my insert page

```
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
String msg = request.getParameter("msg");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chatbox",
        "root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("insert into logs(msg,username) values ('" + msg + "','" + uname + "')");

String query = "select * from logs ";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    out.println(rs.getString(3));
    out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

the problem is value is not getting passed to insert page  and   the result is not getting printed in the inner html    any idea??

Answer (score 0):

`xmlhttp.status == 2000`, try with 200 :)

You should probably be careful about sanitizing user input before running your insert request too, but it has nothing to do with your question.